# UI disappearing after a few seconds

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I've been building a Windows Phone app (8.1) that gets some JSON data, parses it, and then builds UI Elements as necessary. Getting and parsing work fine, and life is nice, but the UI Elements disappear after only a few seconds. An example can be seen [here](http://gfycat.com/GrimPettyAiredaleterrier), where a user clicks a button and the Elements get created, but gets destro. Specifically this piece of code is how I'm implementing it.

```c#
private void doBuild(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e) {
    Button myButton = new Button();
    myButton.Width = 160;
    myButton.Height = 72;
    myButton.Content = "Click Me";
    var margin = myButton.Margin;
    margin.Top = 250;
    margin.Left = 15;
    myButton.Margin = margin;
    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(myButton);
    LayoutRoot.UpdateLayout();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First off, you're not using MVVM, which is a much simpler way to code xaml apps.  I'd strongly suggest you put this down and go learn MVVM on WP8 apps.  Second, nothing in your code here has a problem.  The issue lies somewhere else.  Where, we can't tell you.  You need to debug your code in order to figure out why it's being cleared out.  If you have code that clears your UI, put a breakpoint in it.  Trace execution to determine why it's being called.

Comment: There's a transition effect on your example, how are you doing it? The button disappears right at the end of the slide-in, so I'd search around whatever type of animation you're using (storyboard?)

Comment: @KooKiz There's no other code on the button besides what is mentioned. No storyboarding (honestly wasn't aware this was an option), nothing else. I don't know why the transition is happening.

Comment: What type is `LayoutRoot`, a grid? Can you show us the full exact xaml?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Changer098/2a71adf09234b567eabb, It's a grid. I removed the transition from ChildrenTransitions, so now it doesn't show at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your layout. You've set a width of 0% for the first column of your grid. Since your button is added per default to the first column, its width is set to 0.

Either change the size of your columns, or add the button to another column:

```
private void doBuild(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button myButton = new Button();
    myButton.Width = 160;
    myButton.Height = 72;
    myButton.Content = "Click Me";
    var margin = myButton.Margin;
    margin.Top = 250;
    margin.Left = 15;
    myButton.Margin = margin;

    Grid.SetColumn(myButton, 1);

    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(myButton);
    LayoutRoot.UpdateLayout();
}
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, that solved everything. Thank you so much!